# How are algebras and rings of subsets generated in this paragraph?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

From [ncatlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sigma-algebra#generating_algebras_14)

> What is missing is a simple description of the σ-algebra generated by ℬ.
>
> - For a mere algebra, this is easy; any ℬ can be taken as a subbase of an algebra, the **symmetric unions** of finite families of elements of
>     ℬ form a base of the algebra, and the intersections of finite families
>     of elements of the base form an algebra.
> - For a ring, the only difference is to use intersections only of inhabited families.
> - But for anything from a δ-ring to a σ-algebra, nothing like this will work.

According to the quote, which I don't quite understand,

1. How is an algebra of subsets generated?

   In particular, how is symmetric union defined as a set operation?
   Union is always symmetric. I searched it on the internet, but the
   name seems to have a different meaning for relations.
2. How is a ring of subsets generated?

Thanks and regards!